# Make anchor stay on screen

Tags: html, css

I have 4 anchors displayed on screen:

[image: I have 4 anchors displayed on screen]

After Hover anchors enlarge and they push the last div out of the screen:

[image: After Hover anchors enlarge and they push the last div out of the screen.]

```css
    #box1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color:  black;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    
}

#box1:hover{
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    left:-5%;
    
}

#box2{
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: green;
 transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    
}

#box2:hover{
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    left:-5%;
}


#box3{
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
   
 
    
   
    
    transition: 500ms ;
    
}

#box3:hover{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
     left:-5%;
    
    
}
#box4{
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: darkviolet;

    
}

#box4:hover{
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    left:-5%;
     float: right;
}

.box {
    float: left;
   
}

.boxdiv{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
     <div class="boxdiv">
  <a id="box1" class="box" >
    <div>
        
      </div>
  </a>
     <a id="box2" class="box">
    <div>
        
        </div>
  </a>
     <a id="box3" class="box">
   
  </a>
     <a id="box4" class="box">
    <div>
        
         </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

How do I make the anchors enlarge and the last anchor stay on the screen? I want the anchors to Enlarge but the purple anchor to also stay in the view.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the other three anchors? Should they shrink while the one being hovered enlarges?

Comment: Post the complete code or make a fiddle and give the link so that

Comment: If you make one larger you have to make the others smaller...

Comment: I posted the complete code, and I will try making the others smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.red {
  background: #f00;
}
.green {
  background: #0f0;
}
.blue {
  background: #00f;
}
.orange {
  background: orange;
}
div {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}
.parent a {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  transition: flex-basis .5s ease;
}
.parent a:hover {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#1" class="box red"></a>
  <a href="#2" class="box blue"></a>
  <a href="#3" class="box green"></a>
  <a href="#4" class="box orange"></a>
</div>
```